# ftdetect, ftplugin not working as advertised -- what am I missing?

Tags: vimrc, filetype, ftplugin, ftdetect

I've been reading documentation and trying experiments to register a new filetype in vim, and apply desired indentation rules -- all to no avail.

As an example, say I want to register `*.test` as filetype "test", and I want to auto-indent 2 spaces after a newline after an open <strike>parenthesis</strike> curly-brace.

All the documentation I've read converge on these actions:

1. Create `~/.vim/ftdetect/test.vim`.
2. Create `~/.vim/ftplugin/test.vim`.

There are differences in the various documentation's instructions on the ftplugin file's content, e.g. `set` vs. `setlocal` -- I've tried to exhaust all the variations that I've found, but it just doesn't seem to make a difference.

The end-result of all my trials is that when I edit a `*.test` file, I get no auto-indentation.
I.e. this is my desired behavior:

```
// foo.test
void foo() {
  // I want the cursor to start at 2-spaced indented because of the
  // opening curly-brace above.
```

...but this is the observed behavior

```
// foo.test
void foo() {
// The cursor starts here, in spite of the opening curly-brace above.
```

When I run `:set ft?` in vim, it responds with `filetype=test` -- I assume this means that it is "recognizing" `*.test` files, so I'm at a complete loss why it's not applying indentation rules.

I do not have any other `ftdetect` or `ftplugin` files -- I newly created `~/.vim/ftdetect/` and `~/.vim/ftplugin/` as part of what I described above.
In spite of this, auto-indentation is working correctly for C-family files (`*.c`, `*.cpp`, `*.h`, etc.) and "well-known" filetypes.
I don't understand why auto-indentation works for these "well-known" filetypes when they have no explicit `ftdetect` or `ftplugin` files.

**Please help: I want vim to apply 2-space auto-indentation to `*.test` -- the same as it is applying to C-family files.**

My newly-created `~/.vim/ftdetect/test.vim`:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.test            set filetype=test
```

My newly-created `~/.vim/ftplugin/test.vim`:

```
autocmd FileType test setlocal expandtab
autocmd FileType test setlocal shiftwidth=2
autocmd FileType test setlocal softtabstop=2
autocmd FileType test setlocal cino=(0
autocmd FileType test setlocal syntax=on
```

My `~/.vimrc`:

```
execute pathogen#infect()

filetype plugin indent on
syntax on

set termguicolors
 if has('nvim')
" https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ
set guicursor=n-v-c:block-Cursor/lCursor-blinkon0,i-ci:ver25-Cursor/lCursor,r-cr:hor20-Cursor/lCursor
endif

filetype plugin on
colorscheme Base2Tone_EveningDark

set expandtab                   " Expand tab to spaces
set hlsearch
set number                      " Line numbers

set backspace=indent,eol,start
set cino=(0                     " Indent N chars from the line w/ unclosed paren
set laststatus=2                " Status-line always
set scrolloff=4                 " Start scrolling when cursor is N lines from top/bottom
set shiftwidth=2                " Number of spaces for each step of autoindent
set softtabstop=2               " Number of spaces that <tab> counts for
set textwidth=80

set statusline=
set statusline+=\%F
set statusline+=\%=%l/%L        " Line n/N
set statusline+=%4v             " virtual column
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

set formatoptions+=q            " Allow formatting of comments with "gq"
set formatoptions+=t            " Auto-wrap using textwidth, auto-insert comment leader
set formatoptions+=j            " Remove comment leader when joining lines

set t_ut=

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 1
let g:syntastic_c_config_file = '.syntastic_c_config'
```

My vim version:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Nov 23 2022 14:54:38)
Included patches: 1-875, 878, 881, 883-884, 936, 948, 1046, 1365-1368, 1382, 1401, 4120, 4151-4152, 4214, 4218, 4397, 4428, 4899, 4919, 4921, 4977, 5023-5024, 805, 5043, 5063, 5126
Extra patches: 8.2.3402, 8.2.3403, 8.2.3409, 8.2.3428, 9.0.0490, 9.0.0530, 9.0.0614
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static
+arabic            +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+autocmd           +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autochdir         +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
-balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
-browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +textprop
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +timers
+channel           +iconv             +packages          +title
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        -toolbar
-clientserver      +job               -perl              +user_commands
-clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +vartabs
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +virtualedit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +visual
+comments          +libcall           -python            +visualextra
+conceal           +linebreak         -python3           +viminfo
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +vreplace
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +wildignore
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildmenu
+cursorshape       -lua               -ruby              +windows
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        +writebackup
+diff              +mksession         +signs             -X11
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -xfontset
-dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       -xim
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +statusline        -xpm
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xsmp
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +syntax            -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-mKzl1a/vim-8.1.0875=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not prepend `autocmd`
2. Set `cindent` option
3. Do not set `syntax` option

Comment: In particular, the `ftplugin` file, should simply set the options that need to be set (e.g. `:setlocal sw=2` etc)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Well, it is not prohibited to do some other stuff including autocmd registration. But the rule of the thumb is "to be buffer-local only". E.g. `au <buffer>` etc.

Comment: No, but it will most likely work differently than expected. Because by the time the autocommand is source, the file has been already loaded, so it is too late to become active

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Too late for another FileType, but not for some other events, I mean.

Comment: yes, but still probably not what was expected.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is "working as advertised".

To expand on @Matt's answer…

There are two ways to execute commands, set options, etc. for a given filetype.

- One is to use autocommands on the `FileType` event:

  ```
  autocommand FileType test setlocal expandtab
  ```

  where the command `:setlocal expandtab` is executed when the `FileType` event is triggered with value `test`.

  This is generally what people use *in their `vimrc`* when they want to keep all their stuff together in a single file.
- The other is to simply put the desired commands in a dedicated "ftplugin":

  ```
  " in ftplugin/test.vim
  setlocal expandtab
  ```

  where `ftplugin/test.vim` is sourced automatically by Vim when the `FileType` event is triggered with value `test`.

  This is rather obviously less verbose than the first method, but it also has other advantages:

  - it uses Vim's built-in mechanism in the most canonical way possible
  - it doesn't add `n` more autocommands to an already towering pile of autocommands, which can hurt performance if it is not done correctly.

Basically, what you tried doesn't work because it is a mish-mash of the two methods above, where you add `FileType` autocommands where they don't make sense.

Here is what should happen:

1. The `FileType` event is triggered with value `test`.
2. `ftplugin/test.vim` is sourced.
3. A bunch of options are set for the current buffer.

Here is what actually happens:

1. The `FileType` event is triggered with value `test`.
2. `ftplugin/test.vim` is sourced.
3. A number of autocommands are added for the `FileType` event with value `test`.
4. None of the desired options are set for the current buffer and the number of `test` autocommands augments as you edit more `.test` files:

   ```
   :e 1.test
     - no options
     - 4 "test" autocommands
   :e 2.test
     - options are set because of the autocommands
     - 8 "test" autocommands
   :e 3.test
     - options are set 2 times because of the autocommands
     - 12 "test" autocommands
   :e 4.test
     - options are set 3 times because of the autocommands
     - 16 "test" autocommands
   etc.
   ```

That is not good.

The fix is thus to write your ftplugin properly:

```
setlocal expandtab
setlocal shiftwidth=2
setlocal softtabstop=2
setlocal cinoptions=(0
```

Note that the following command is incorrect for a few reasons:

```
setlocal syntax=on
```

- You are confusing the `:help :syntax` command and the `:help 'syntax'` option.
- Syntax highlighting is a global feature, so there is no point in trying to make it local.
- The `syntax` option is local anyway so `setlocal` is not necessary.
- You are assigning the `on` syntax to your `test` buffer, which is certainly not the desired outcome.

So…

- If you want to enable syntax highlighting, put `syntax on` in your `vimrc`, where it belongs.
- If you want to assign a specific syntax different from the one that is automatically inferred from the filetype to the current buffer, put `set syntax=<whatever>` in your ftplugin. Since you didn't hint otherwise, you probably don't need this.

Comment: `set syntax=test` is only needed when globally using command `syntax manual` instead of `syntax on`. Otherwise, one will end up setting the syntax option (and, also, sourcing syntax script) twice in a row.

Comment: Good point, I will amend the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! In the "The fix is thus to write your ftplugin properly" section of your answer, I found it was also necessary to add `setlocal cindent`, which I got from @Matt 's answer. Between both your answers, I can confirm that `ftdetect` and `ftplugin` are indeed "working as advertised" :)